# how to define triggers in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model `Idea` I want to trigger the date it's validated. how to tell django to automatically write validation date each time `Field` state is updated to `validated` value ?

Comment: Have you tried Django signals when `Field` state updated and execute your function to update `validated` value ?

Comment: first time to discover django signals

Comment: There isn't any need for signals, djangos docs on datefields document `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` very well

Comment: @Sayse I thought he needs to updated `validated` field some other time  not the creation time.

Comment: @RajaSimon - Luckily, we are able to VTC as unclear :) (or too broad)

Comment: yes that it I have posting date that used auto_now and validation date that needs something like signals to be writtent according to state field value beeing updated

Comment: @Sayse concur...  OP needs to update the question with relevant code.

Comment: @user2080105 Can you include your relevant model code?

Comment: i have done it. I am gonna write an answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Proposition)
def proposition_update_handler(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.state=='validée':
        instance.validation_date = datetime.now()
    elif instance.state=='réalisée':
        instance.execution_date = datetime.now()
    elif instance.state=='clôturée':
        instance.closing_date = datetime.now()
    elif instance.state=='rejetée':
        instance.rejection_date = datetime.now()
```